# How can I parse JSON file in PHP with structure like this

Tags: php, json

**How can I parsing JSON file in PHP with structure like this.**

```
{
"url": "http://lotto.mthai.com",
"result": {
    "extractorData": {
        "url": "http://lotto.mthai.com",
        "resourceId": "85407efc3b77dc0c03350101dbe4d644",
        "data": [
            {
                "group": [
                    {
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "text": "รางวัลที่ 1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "number": [
                            {
                                "text": "511825"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "text": "เลขท้าย 2 ตัว"
                            }
                        ],
                        "number": [
                            {
                                "text": "14"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "text": "รางวัลเลขหน้า 3 ตัว"
                            }
                        ],
                        "number": [
                            {
                                "text": "111 775"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "text": "รางวัลเลขท้าย 3 ตัว"
                            }
                        ],
                        "number": [
                            {
                                "text": "880 937"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "text": "รางวัลข้างเคียงรางวัลที่ 1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "number": [
                            {
                                "text": "511824 511826"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "text": "ผลสลากกินแบ่งรัฐบาล รางวัลที่ 2"
                            }
                        ],
                        "number": [
                            {
                                "text": "041316 051696 174632 262383 301461"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "text": "ผลสลากกินแบ่งรัฐบาล ตรวจหวย รางวัลที่ 3"
                            }
                        ],
                        "number": [
                            {
                                "text": "151368 192853 218010 381563 441994 593440 608530 958702 960236 991980"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "text": "ผลสลากกินแบ่งรัฐบาล ตรวจหวย รางวัลที่ 4"
                            }
                        ],
                        "number": [
                            {
                                "text": "005297 143532 183328 308705 457316 561361 692884 813010 891564 984090 027175 151262 203467 309366 464915 580426 725352 835838 895659 986826 034358 160471 207682 426987 477041 626565 727202 840597 927093 990225 055970 175123 221131 428397 542542 674499 761363 883250 936443 994258 100858 175672 285542 434884 558734 692634 795866 888874 967956 996299"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "text": "ผลสลากกินแบ่งรัฐบาล ตรวจหวย รางวัลที่ 5"
                            }
                        ],
                        "number": [
                            {
                                "text": "018823 074535 190371 313865 352942 456747 541518 709349 861423 919589 030122 085212 200070 318968 359324 474167 571715 734617 862093 924308 047376 102785 206781 320576 376900 481372 573928 739412 863966 928572 049905 128721 209050 324031 386258 505554 599073 767614 867382 958601 051129 132159 227324 326875 396408 506582 637094 786639 869522 960148 051242 137750 265952 327702 405928 507898 654254 788560 878668 962359 052418 156993 269239 330428 416971 508844 664963 805061 881503 971836 054447 157814 286374 330762 434541 526775 705692 811851 890915 983191 060979 176311 301301 336489 451863 529673 707115 819033 902456 983528 061270 184563 308537 352516 455643 535855 707396 829248 908825 999541"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "pageData": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "timestamp": 1464855539981
    }
}
}
```

*json file exported from import.io*

I want to parsing **title** and **number** in group and keep it in array.
I tried many ways but always got error.

Thanks you.

Comment: The JSON text is valid: good. So you want to loop over the content stored in a temporary deeply nested PHP array `d` and loop only over the title/number entries inside the dictionaries/maps of the `d['result']['data']['extractorData']['group'| sub array? Please provide at least one of the many ways youtried - possibly the most promising one (from your perspective). Thanks. And always check the validtiy if this is external input!

Comment: here my recent tried. error at line 6 Invalid argument supplied for foreach().
    `<?php
$json = 'data.json';
$obj = json_decode($json, true); 

foreach($obj['result']['extractorData']['data'] as $mydata) {
 foreach ($mydata['group'] as $mygroup) {
  foreach ($mygroup['number'] as $mynumber) {
   $lotto = $mynumber['text'];
   echo $lotto;
  }
 }
}
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood your question you could organize your JSON like below:

```
       "group": [
            {
                "title": "Some text",
                "number": "511825"
            },
            {
                "title": "Some text 2",
                "number": "98989"
            },
```

Comment: In that the OP was clear:The given file format shall be parsed, so the format is given (in his opinion). Please cf. my comment for how I understood and possibly amend it, when I skipped something important. Thanks.